# Carnation Instant Breakfast substitute

Tags: kashrut-kosher, food, dairy, chalav-yisrael-jewishmilk

Is there any non-dairy (or chalav yisrael) substitute for Carnation Instant Breakfast?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about Judaism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First and foremost, if this is for someone who needs liquid nutrition, you *must* check with a nutritionist before trying something different.  *Saving a life trumps kashrut*.

Additionally, many rabbis who normally require *chalav yisrael* will allow non-chalav-yisrael for someone seriously sick (even if not life-threateningly so).  Or as the TV ads say, "ask your rabbi if Carnation is right for you."

But to answer your question: There's probably something in Israel, but I don't know how you'd find it.

Koshervitamins.com has powders for [soy-protein drinks](http://www.koshervitamins.com/shop/stores_app/Browse_dept_items.asp?showpage=1&Search_Text=shake&PageIndex=1) and [whey-protein drinks](http://www.koshervitamins.com/shop/stores_app/Browse_dept_items.asp?showpage=1&Search_Text=cholov&PageIndex=1), if you consult with a nutritionist, one of those might work.